# How do I specify the mysql jar in the classpath from the command line?

Tags: java

I am trying to run the mybatis tool from command line, and I have already specified the mysql path, but it still told me com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found!

```
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

java -cp ./:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.jar -jar ./mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2.jar -configfile xmlconfig.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-jar` will actually override the `-cp`.  So if you use the `-jar` make sure you have a manifest that includes all the locations of your needed mysql jars.

Alternatively use just the `-cp` and specify the package and class name of your Main class.

Something like.

```
java -cp ./:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.jar:./mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2.jar to.my.main.MainClass -configfile xmlconfig.xm
```